# IE not supporting some CSS3 styling

Tags: internet-explorer

I am having a problem with IE. I am using some css3 style on my current project. On all other browsers I have tested it on Firefox, chrome and safari and it looks amazing. But on IE it looks like my room(doesn't look good).

I need some advice please. I know the percentage of IE user this days is very very low compare to the other browsers. My question is should I rewrite my css3 to just standard CSS especially for the ones that doesn't support IE or should I annoy it and just using PHP to alert users that the contains might no looks right because of their browser type and recommend them to download, chrome or firefox?

An example of one of the issue is with the navigation bar.

```
<nav>
    <ul>    
    <li>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    </li>                   
<li><a href="about.php">AboutUs</a></li>                        
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>                   
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
text-align:center;
}
nav li{
text-align:center;list-style: none;
   float: left;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul {
    z-index:50;
    background: #FFFFFF; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li:hover {
        background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%,#FFFFFF 40%);
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;

        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; 
        padding: 10px 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #760076;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #FFFFFF;
            }
            nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE? IE9+ should do the job (almost) as well as other modern browsers do...

Comment: @Teemu my IE version is 9.0.8112.16421. So it is version 9

Comment: And you've used a proper HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) on the very first line of the file, and without any preceeding characters? Notice also, that some CSS properties need a vendor prefix to work in IE9.

Comment: @Teemu yes i have use `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I have use `vendor prefix`

Comment: @Teemu I will update my question to show u an example of one of the issue

Comment: For the future, this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be useful.

Comment: @Teemu I have update my question to show an example

Comment: "percentage of IE user this days is very very low compare to the other browsers." Incorrect. IE usage remains >50%.

Comment: @EricLaw http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp THE static is going down not UP and i dont see any 50%

Comment: @EricLaw http://www.ie6countdown.com/ u will se china is the higher users of IE and even with that it not 50% Tt's less than 8%. I did my research before i said that

Comment: @EmilyKenpachi Did you think about the fact, that even 1% of 2-3000000000 is really a lot of people. I wouldn't throw away a potential of 30 million visitors...

Comment: @Teemu I was trying to point out the % to EricLaw that it wasn't 50% but much lower than that. I know the percentage might look small but in Earth population is is actually a large number

Comment: @Emily: You should read the giant disclaimer on the W3Schools page where they say "These numbers are meaningless when applied to the internet at large." Here are some statistically-sound numbers: http://www.netmarketshare.com/

Comment: @EricLaw the static is done using the number of windows PC and laptop sold and the Firefox, chrome etc is done by the number of downloads of those broswers. Thats why the static is high on netmarketshare.com. watch in about 10 years times when alot of people learn to like mac, safari statics will be high

Comment: No, the numbers are generated based on actual browsing, not the thing you made up. Having said that, I'm happy to agree that in 10 years, marketshare statistics might be different. Today, in 2013, IE still has >50% share.

Answer (score 0):

For example for IE9:

```
nav ul {
    :
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #BBBBBB 100%);
    :
}
```

and

```
nav ul li:hover {
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 40%);
        :
}
```

IE10 works with similar rules, only without vendor prefixes.

Comment: I tried this with the `ms-liner` and unfortunately  its doesn't make much different

Comment: @EmilyKenpachi I've only IE10 at hands right now, the page looked same as in Chrome29 and FF23 in IE10 and IE9 modes. Though the emulate mode is not very reliable...

Comment: thanks but remember not many people have IE10, I think i should just forget about it and will alert the user to use a better browser because some styling will not work that way it should